# Post from partial View change the URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view with a contact form.

My problem is that after the form is posted, the controller is redirecting to the actual URL of the partial view: ("LocalHost:/Views/ContactUs/MoreInformationRequest.cshtml")

I want to keep the same URL and to show only the ViewData["MsgSent"] message.

**This is the call to the partial view:**

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/ContactUs/MoreInformationRequest.cshtml")
```

**The View:**

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm( "MoreInformationRequest","ContactUs"))
    {
      .....

       <input type="submit" value="send" /><br />
       @ViewData["MsgSent"]

     }
```

**The Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MoreInformationRequest(ContactUs contacts)
    {

      .....

        ViewData["MsgSent"] = "Message sent!"
        return View();

    }
```

Comment: Are you fine with using Jquery's ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning I came out with this solution - to redirect to the same page using:

```
Request.Redirect("~/");
```

But I did not like this solution so I solved this by using client side code to send the data to the controller:

```
    <script>
                    var request;
                    $('#formMoreInformationRequest').submit(function () {

                        var Name = document.getElementById('Name');
                        var Phone = document.getElementById('Phone');

                       // without this the validations in the page are not working.
                        if (Name.value == "") {                            
                            return false;}

                        else if (Phone.value == "") {                           
                            return false; }

                        else {

                            $('#overlay').show()


                            if (request) {
                                request.abort();
                            }

                            // setup some local variables
                            var $form = $(this);

                            // let's select and cache all the fields
                            var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

                            // serialize the data in the form
                            var serializedData = $form.serialize();


                            // let's disable the inputs for the duration of the ajax request
                            $inputs.prop("disabled", true);


                            // fire off the request to /form.php
                            request = $.ajax({
                                url: "/ContactUs/MoreInformationRequest",
                                type: "post",
                                data: serializedData
                            });


                            // callback handler that will be called on success
                            request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                $('#overlay').hide()
                                $("#moreInfoMsg").html("Message Sent!");
                            });

                            // callback handler that will be called on failure
                            request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                $('#overlay').hide()

                                // log the error to the console
                                alert(
                                    "The following error occured: " +
                                    textStatus, errorThrown
                                );
                            });

                            // callback handler that will be called regardless
                            // if the request failed or succeeded
                            request.always(function () {
                                // reenable the inputs
                                $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
                            });


                            // prevent default posting of form       
                            event.preventDefault();

                        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a redirect to redisplay the page that loads the partial view:

```
return RedirectToAction("OriginalAction");
```

You could also return a specific view, particularly the view from the original action:

```
return View("OriginalView");
```

Comment: basically it's working  but the URL is still changed and I have other elements in the page that does not load right. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

post to the server using jQuery and return false from the javascript function to stop the default processing (i.e. sending to the new url from the controller.